# Should I rely on User.Identity value?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, security

I am interested in security connected with ASP.NET applications. When I am developing my websites I extensively use `User.Identity.Name` value to identify user. I am wondering if there is a possibility to modify request so that client could change this value and become other user. If so how to identify users then and how to distinguish superuser safely?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can rely on this value. The whole security of ASP.NET relies on it. It is stored in an encrypted cookie that can only be decrypted by the application. If a malicious user tries to substitute the value of this cookie with another username he will not be able to encrypt the cookie because he doesn't have the machine keys.

Comment: your answer seems to be useful. any useful link how to implement this ?? As this is not the part of question but still will love to implement this feature on my project as well :) If possible kindly help with the related links and videos

Comment: What exactly do you need to implement? Normally the http://www.asp.net/mvc website should contain enough reading materials.

Comment: i  want to implement  `SuperUser`, `Admin` and `User` functionality which is related to security part.

Comment: Great, so you may start at this section: http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/security But I also encourage you to go through the other sections from this site.

Comment: thanks a lot :) Yeah surely. I have started giving a try to `MVC` also. So I guess this link is pretty much useful for me